# How to compare values of two objects after an API call, check for nulls or empties

Tags: javascript

I have an original object that is modified after an API call. I need to make sure that any fields that were originally not empty are reassigned to their original value. For example if `articleTitle` was initially filled out, and then after the API call it gets replaced with an empty value, I want to reassign it back to the original `articleTitle` value from the old object.

The two objects have the same keys, but I can't assume that the data coming back from the response is always going to be valid (but the original object always has valid data, that's why I need to reassign any empty fields to original values).

I (kinda) have a theoretically functional method, however I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this. Here's what I have:

```
function evaluateEmptyValues = (originalReference, reference) {
    // Get keys of both reference objects
    var newReference = Object.entries(reference);
    var oldReference = Object.entries(originalReference);

    // Get length of both reference objects
    var newReferenceLength = newReference.length;
    var oldReferenceLength = oldReference.length;

    // Double check objects are of the same length -- they always should be
    if (newReferenceLength == oldReferenceLength) {
        // Cycle through both objects
        for (var i = 0; i < newReference.length; i++) {
            console.log('i is ' + i);

            // Again, these two lengths should be equal
            if (newReference[i].length == oldReference[i].length) {
                // Check if elements in current iteration is an object --
                // if one is an object, then the other SHOULD also be
                if ((typeof(newReference[i][j]) == 'object' &&
                    typeof(oldReference[i][j]) == 'object'
                ) {
                    // If both are objects, repeat lines 3 and 4
                    var currentNewReference = Object.entries(newReference[i][j]);
                    var currentOldReference = Object.entries(oldReference[i][j]);

                    // Get their lengths
                    var currentNewReferenceLength = currentNewReference.length;
                    var currentOldReferenceLength = currentOldReference.length;

                    // Both should be of the same length
                    if (currentNewReferenceLength == currentOldReferenceLength) {
                        for (var io = 0; io < currentNewReferenceLength.length; io++) {
                            console.log('io is ' + io);

                            // Both should also be of the same length
                            if (currentNewReference[io].length == currentOldReference[io].length) {
                                // For each iteration...
                                for (var jo = 0; jo < currentNewReference[io].length; jo++) {
                                    // Check for empty values
                                    if (currentNewReference[io][jo] == undefined ||
                                        currentNewReference[io][jo] == null ||
                                        (typeof(currentNewReference[io][jo]) == 'string' && currentNewReference[io][jo].trim() == '')
                                    ) {
                                        // If empty, then reassign the empty value in the new reference
                                        // object with the value of the field from the old reference
                                        // object, regardless of whether or not the old value is also empty/null
                                        currentNewReference[io][jo] = currentOldReference[io][jo];
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                // Serious problem
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Serious problem
                    }
                } else {
                    // Cycle through current field
                    for (var j = 0; j < newReference[i].length; j++) {
                        // Check for nulls or empties
                        if (newReference[i][j] == undefined ||
                            newReference[i][j] == null ||
                            (typeof(newReference[i][j]) == 'string' && newReference[i][j].trim() == '')
                        ) {
                            // Assign old value to new value, regardless of
                            // whether or not old value is also empty
                            newReference[i][j] = oldReference[i][j];
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Serious problem
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Serious problem
    }
```

I doubt this is a very scalable or maintainable approach, and I'm wondering if there are any suggestions on enhancing this function, preferably using ES5, unless the ES6+ version works in most browsers.

---

For some reference, here are the two objects:

Here, articleTitle is empty.
[image: img1]

Here, it is filled out from the API call. This is expected and needed, however imagine if it was the other way around, and articleTitle came back empty in the newReference after the API call
[image: img2]

---

Edit:

Using the accepted answer plus an adjustment, this solved my specific problem:

```
function evaluateEmptyValues(reference, originalReference) {
    var vm = this;

    // Get keys and values of both reference objects
    referenceLength = Object.entries(reference).length;
    originalReferenceLength = Object.entries(originalReference).length;

    if (referenceLength == originalReferenceLength) {
        try {
            // Cycle through both objects
            for (var prop in reference) {
                    if (reference[prop] != undefined || reference[prop] != null) {
                        if (typeof (reference[prop]) == 'string' && reference[prop].trim() != '') {
                            // If both current elements are objects, recurse
                            if (typeof reference[prop] == 'object' && typeof originalReference[prop] == 'object') {
                                vm.evaluateEmptyValues(reference[prop], originalReference[prop])
                            }
                            // If both current elements are arrays, recurse
                            if (Array.isArray(reference[prop]) && typeof Array.isArray(originalReference[prop])) {
                                reference[prop].forEach((item, index) => vm.evaluateEmptyValues(item, originalReference[prop][index]));
                            }
                            // If new value is null, empty or undefined, assign it to old value,
                            // regardless of whether or not the old value was also null/empty.
                            //
                            ///// This is to ensure that no existing previous values are
                            ///// overwritten with any nulls or empty values
                        } else {
                            reference[prop] = originalReference[prop];
                        }
                } else {
                    reference[prop] = originalReference[prop];
                }
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    console.log(reference);
```

Comment: Adding some helper functions like `isEmptyString()` or `getTypeOf()`would help make it a bit more readable and move simple tasks out of the main flow. Then sometimes doing things like that makes it easier to see ways to improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your function by a lot using recursion and a `for ... in` loop. I made two test objects to illustrate all the cases of your original example. In case it hits an array of objects it will iterate through that array and check for empty values recursively as well. Please see snippet below:

```js
function evaluateEmptyValues(reference, originalReference) {
  if (reference.length == originalReference.length) {
    for (var prop in reference) {
      if (typeof reference[prop] == 'object' && typeof originalReference[prop] == 'object') {
        evaluateEmptyValues(reference[prop], originalReference[prop])
      }
      if (Array.isArray(reference[prop]) && typeof Array.isArray(originalReference[prop])) {
        reference[prop].forEach((item, index) => evaluateEmptyValues(item, originalReference[prop][index]));
      }
      if (reference[prop] == undefined || reference[prop] == null ||
        (typeof (reference[prop]) == 'string' && reference[prop].trim() == '')) {
        reference[prop] = originalReference[prop];
      }
    }
  }
}

const original = {
  name: "Jack",
  employee: {
    firstName: "Nathan",
    favoriteAnimal: {
      species: "Donkey",
      nature: "Lazy"
    },
    favoriteBeverages: [
      { name: "Beer", temperature: "Cold" },
      { name: "More beer", temperature: "Colder" }
    ]
  },
  occupation: "Plumber"
}

const newObject = {
  name: "Jack",
  employee: {
    firstName: " ",
    favoriteAnimal: {
      species: null,
      nature: "Lazy"
    },
    favoriteBeverages: [
      { name: "Beer", temperature: ""},
      { name: null, temperature: "Colder" }
    ]
  },
  occupation: undefined
}

evaluateEmptyValues(newObject, original);
console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of using lot's of if conditions, you can try [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#isEqual), and use `isEqual` method which do a deep comparison between two values ( in your case two objects ), your code can be much cleaner as well.

```
var object = { 'a': 1 };
var other = { 'a': 1 };

_.isEqual(object, other);
// => true
```

Comment: +1 Interesting suggestion, however I'm trying to use as less extra libraries are possible. I will use this answer if no one has any other suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a recursive function. Something like this.

```
function mapper(oldObj, newObj) {
  Object.entries(oldObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (!newObj[key]) {
      newObj[key] = value;
    } else if (Array.isArray(newObj[key])) {
      newObj[key].forEach((o, i) => mapper(oldObj[key][i], o));
    } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(newObj[key]) === "[object Object]") {
      mapper(oldObj[key], newObj[key]);
    }
  });
  return newObj;
}

const next = mapper(oldObj, newObj);
```

This will basically loop over all the items in the original object, and set the key/value in the new object if it doesn't exist.